# Freedesktop Appstream XML: DTD?

Tags: xml-parsing, metadata, dtd, freedesktop.org

I'm currently writing metainfo for GUI and non-GUI applications.

For that, I'm extensively studying [the official metainfo documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/docs/chap-Metadata.html#spec-component-filespec), but its unspecific to ambiguous in many places, to put it mildly (optionality, multiplicity of tags, ordering, …; in fact, the doc is using `<tag/>` to define tags that actually have content `<tag>foobar</tag>` and those that' don't, `<tag prop="foobar"/>`, alike).

Since I'm planning adhere to a format that will probably be rejected by a parser if validation fails, I'd like to have the DTD that parser uses. This is XML, after all, and I'm pretty certain the developers chose XML exactly *because* it comes with a schema specification language.

I can't find that schema, however. I tried finding my way through the source code of `appstream-generator` and `appstream-cli`, but I had no success.

Comment: Just a note that I can't remember the last time I saw an XML dialect specified with a full DTD, and would find it more likely to see a schema written in XSD or RelaxNG.

Comment: @IMSoP ah, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

With [IMSoP's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727279/freedesktop-appstream-xml-dtd?noredirect=1#comment110926584_62727279) I started looking into the [appstream source code](https://github.com/ximion/appstream/). Turns out:

Appstream *used* to have an XSD. They deleted it, because they didn't maintain it for four years and it fell out of sync with the documentation.

I cannot applaud that decision, though I find it understandable, given that maintaining a schema takes time, and duplicating the effort of a parseable schema in a separate validating CLI tool simply eats time.